Rapidfuzz critical error when using workers != 1
When using the latest version 3.9.6 of rapidfuzz, I get a critical error when using workers != 1, i.e. I cannot use multi-processing to speed-up string comparisons:
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
The error does not occur in rapidfuzz 3.5.2, however.
Code generating the error:
import rapidfuzz
from rapidfuzz import process

print(rapidfuzz.__version__)

process.cdist(['tree'], ['beer'], workers=1)
process.cdist(['tree'], ['beer'], workers=2)

What is causing the issue? Apart from downgrading, is there a fix?
Update: Reported as issue #403 in the rapidfuzz GitHub.

Seems like a bug in the library. This is something to report on their public repository issues. I doubt anyone can infer what is wrong from what you provided.

I have reported the issue on their GitHub :)
